# Combine multiple rows to one after group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

**UPDATE:**
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5fGUTSsAhGRPYPk33wDSzz/0

Sorry for asking the question very similar to the previous one, but I am really stuck here.

There are multiple tables:

- items → items_roles → roles
- items → zones →  roles_zones → roles

Structure:

- items: id, zone_id
- items_roles: role_id, item_id
- zones: id
- roles_zones: role_id, zone_id
- roles: id, role_type_id,

I am trying to add role fields to items, it should take role_type and it is value from items_zones and if it is NULL fetch fallback value from zone (roles_zones).

I started with:

```sql
SELECT 
    items.id,
    (z_roles.role_type_id) as z_role_type_id,
    (z_roles.id) as z_role_id,
    MAX(i_roles.role_type_id) as i_role_type_id,
    MAX(i_roles.id) as i_role_id
FROM 
    items
LEFT JOIN 
    zones as j_zones ON j_zones.id = items.zone_id
LEFT JOIN 
    roles_zones ON roles_zones.zone_id = j_zones.id
LEFT JOIN 
    roles as z_roles ON (z_roles.id = roles_zones.role_id)
LEFT JOIN 
    items_roles ON items_roles.item_id = items.id
LEFT JOIN 
    roles as i_roles ON items_roles.role_id = i_roles.id
                     AND (z_roles.role_type_id = i_roles.role_type_id)
WHERE 
    items.id = 834
GROUP BY
    items.id, z_roles.role_type_id, z_roles.id
ORDER BY 
    i_role_id;
```

Looks right:

```
id  |z_role_type_id |z_role_id |i_role_type_id |i_role_id |
----+---------------+----------+---------------+----------+
834 |5              |111       |5              |68        |
834 |11             |120       |11             |120       |
834 |7              |77        |               |          |
834 |2              |2         |               |          |
834 |12             |91        |               |          |
834 |4              |78        |               |          |
834 |8              |36        |               |          |
```

And now this query:

```
SELECT
    items.id,
    z_roles.role_type_id as z_role_type_id,
    z_roles.id as z_role_id,
    MAX(i_roles.role_type_id) AS i_role_type_id,
    MAX(i_roles.id) AS i_role_id,
    MAX(CASE
           WHEN (i_roles.role_type_id = 5) THEN i_roles.id
           WHEN (z_roles.role_type_id = 5) THEN z_roles.id
        END) AS role_type_5_value,
    MAX(CASE
           WHEN (i_roles.role_type_id = 11) THEN i_roles.id
           WHEN (z_roles.role_type_id = 11) THEN z_roles.id
        END) AS role_type_11_value,
    MAX(CASE
           WHEN (i_roles.role_type_id = 7) THEN i_roles.id
           WHEN (z_roles.role_type_id = 7) THEN z_roles.id
        END) AS role_type_7_value
FROM 
    items
LEFT JOIN 
    zones AS j_zones ON j_zones.id = items.zone_id
LEFT JOIN 
    roles_zones ON roles_zones.zone_id = j_zones.id
LEFT JOIN 
    roles AS z_roles ON (z_roles.id = roles_zones.role_id)
LEFT JOIN 
    items_roles ON items_roles.item_id = items.id
LEFT JOIN 
    roles AS i_roles ON items_roles.role_id = i_roles.id
                     AND (z_roles.role_type_id = i_roles.role_type_id)
WHERE 
    items.id = 834
GROUP BY 
    items.id,
    z_roles.role_type_id,
    z_roles.id
ORDER BY 
    items.id, i_role_id;
```

Generates this:

```
 id  | z_role_type_id | z_role_id | i_role_type_id | i_role_id | role_type_5_value | role_type_11_value | role_type_7_value 
-----+----------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------
 834 |              5 |       111 |              5 |        68 |               111 |                    |                  
 834 |             11 |       120 |             11 |       120 |                   |                120 |                  
 834 |              7 |        77 |                |           |                   |                    |                77
 834 |              2 |         2 |                |           |                   |                    |                  
 834 |             12 |        91 |                |           |                   |                    |                  
 834 |              4 |        78 |                |           |                   |                    |                  
 834 |              8 |        36 |                |           |                   |                    |                  
(7 rows)
```

Multiple rows and wrong value for `role_type_5_value`. Probably because of MAX aggregator. Is it possible to use something like `first` aggregator (because rows ordered by i_role_id and first results are right)?

I want this:

```
 id  | role_type_5_value | role_type_11_value | role_type_7_value 
-----+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------
 834 |                68 |                120 |                77
```

I tried to `group by` by aggregated fields, (`role_type_5_value`, `role_type_11_value`, `role_type_7_value`) but this is simply not working.

Comment: please provide the sample data to populate each of these tables: `items`, `item_roles`, `role_zones`, `zones`, `roles`

Comment: Without sample data for each of those tables, we cannot make progress, and your question will sit waiting for an answer indefinitely. I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Take a look when you have a moment, please: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5fGUTSsAhGRPYPk33wDSzz/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: removing the unneeded bridge-tables from the main query and squeeze them into `EXISTS()` terms will simplify your query.(you only need three tables, the rest is glue)

Second: don't put all your terms in the `GROUP BY` clause.

---

```
SELECT
  i0.id
   , MAX(CASE
    WHEN (r1.role_type_id = 5) THEN r1.id
    WHEN (r0.role_type_id = 5) THEN r0.id
  END) AS role_type_5_value
  , MAX(CASE
    WHEN (r1.role_type_id = 11) THEN r1.id
    WHEN (r0.role_type_id = 11) THEN r0.id
  END) AS role_type_11_value
  , MAX(CASE
    WHEN (r1.role_type_id = 7) THEN r1.id
    WHEN (r0.role_type_id = 7) THEN r0.id
  END) AS role_type_7_value

FROM items i0
LEFT JOIN roles AS r0
  ON EXISTS ( SELECT*
        FROM zones AS z0
        JOIN roles_zones rz ON rz.zone_id = z0.id
        WHERE z0.id = i0.zone_id
        AND r0.id = rz.role_id)

LEFT JOIN roles AS r1
  ON EXISTS ( SELECT*
        FROM items_roles ir
        WHERE ir.item_id = i0.id
        AND ir.role_id = r1.id
        AND r0.role_type_id = r1.role_type_id
        )

WHERE i0.id = 834
GROUP BY i0.id
         -- r0.role_type_id,
         -- r0.id
ORDER BY i0.id;
```